# Resize image to full width and fixed height with Picasso

Tags: java, android, imageview, image-resizing, picasso

I have a vertical LinearLayout where one of the items is an `ImageView` loaded using Picasso. I need to rise the image's width to the full device width, and to display the center part of the image cropped by a fixed height (150dp). I currently have the following code:

```
Picasso.with(getActivity()) 
    .load(imageUrl) 
    .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder) 
    .error(R.drawable.error) 
    .resize(screenWidth, imageHeight)
    .centerInside() 
    .into(imageView);
```

Which values should I put into `screenWidth` and `imageHeight` (=150dp)?

Answer (score 506, accepted):

You are looking for:

```
.fit().centerCrop()
```

What these mean:

- `fit` - wait until the `ImageView` has been measured and resize the image to exactly match its size.
- `centerCrop` - scale the image honoring the aspect ratio until it fills the size. Crop either the top and bottom or left and right so it matches the size exactly.

Comment: What should be the height of the imageView? I don't want a fixed height for my imageView. It should change according to the height of the image.

Comment: `.fit().centerInside()` worked for me where just using `.centerInside()` was crashing with `Center inside requires calling resize with positive width and height.` error message.

Comment: @Rock Lee, you need to resize it : ' .load(url)
    .resize(targetWidth, targetHeight) '.........

Comment: `.fit().centerCrop()` or `.fit().centerInside()` is not working. Image is not loading in `imageView`. without `.fit()` image is loading fine. I am not using `.resize()` in both cases.

Comment: how to resize it without cropping it from any side and also maintaining the aspect

Answer (score 2):

In some case the fit() is useless. Before you must wait for the width and height measurement to end. So you can use globallayoutlistener. for example;

```
imageView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                Picasso.with(getActivity())
                        .load(imageUrl)
                        .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
                        .error(R.drawable.error)
                        .resize(screenWidth, imageHeight)
                        .fit
                        .centerInside()
                        .into(imageView);
                imageView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            }
        });
```