# Resize image to full width and variable height with Picasso

Tags: android, picasso

I have a listView with an adapter that contains `ImageView` of variable size (width and height). I need resize the pictures load with Picasso to the max width of layout and a variable height given by the aspect ratio of the picture.

I have checked this question:
[Resize image to full width and fixed height with Picasso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20823249/resize-image-to-full-width-and-fixed-height-with-picasso)

The `fit()` works but I haven't found nothing to keep the aspect ratio of the picture.

This code partially works if I fixed the height in the layout of the adapter:

```
Picasso.with(this.context).load(message_pic_url)
.placeholder(R.drawable.profile_wall_picture)
.fit().centerInside()
.into(holder.message_picture);
```

But it generates blank spaces between the pictures of the listView because the pictures may be that not have that height.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Finally I solved it doing a transformation of Picasso, here is the snippet:

```
    Transformation transformation = new Transformation() {

        @Override
        public Bitmap transform(Bitmap source) {
            int targetWidth = holder.message_picture.getWidth();

            double aspectRatio = (double) source.getHeight() / (double) source.getWidth();
            int targetHeight = (int) (targetWidth * aspectRatio);
            Bitmap result = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(source, targetWidth, targetHeight, false);
            if (result != source) {
                // Same bitmap is returned if sizes are the same
                source.recycle();
            }
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        public String key() {
            return "transformation" + " desiredWidth";
        }
    };

    mMessage_pic_url = message_pic_url;

    Picasso.with(this.context)
        .load(message_pic_url)
        .error(android.R.drawable.stat_notify_error)
        .transform(transformation)
        .into(holder.message_picture, new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                holder.progressBar_picture.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError() {
                Log.e(LOGTAG, "error");
                holder.progressBar_picture.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
    });
```

This line is for customize with your desired width:

```
int targetWidth = holder.message_picture.getWidth();
```

Additionally this snipped include Callback for loading hide and error drawable built-in Picasso.

If you need more information to debug any error, you MUST implement a custom listener (Picasso builder) beacuse the `onError` `Callback` information is "null". You only know that there is an error for UI behavior.

I hope this helps someone to save many hours.

Comment: It looks like you're only recycling the source if it's the same as the result. Wouldn't you want to recycle it regardless and just return the result?

Comment: @Wenger, No, Picasso complains if you do that.

Comment: Great!! Really great

Comment: Yep, this worked. But in mycase I had to set the ImageView width to match_parent, or a specific width. "wrap_content" returns 0 (zero) in the transformation, and raises an exception.

Comment: While scrolling, sometimes `holder.message_picture.getWidth()` returns 0 and it causes an error `width and height must be > 0`. Any ideas how to fix this error?

Answer (score 97):

As of Picasso 2.4.0, [this operation is now directly supported](https://github.com/square/picasso/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#version-240-2014-11-04).  Simply add a `.resize()` request with one of the dimensions as `0`.  For example, to have a variable width, your call would become:

```
Picasso.with(this.context)
       .load(message_pic_url)
       .placeholder(R.drawable.profile_wall_picture)
       .resize(0, holder.message_picture.getHeight()),
       .into(holder.message_picture);
```

Note that this call uses `.getHeight()` and therefore assumes the `message_picture` has already been measured.  If that isn't the case, such as when you have inflated a new view in a `ListAdapter`, you can delay this call until after measurement by adding an `OnGlobalLayoutListener` to the view:

```
holder.message_picture.getViewTreeObserver()
      .addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            // Wait until layout to call Picasso
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                // Ensure we call this only once
                imageView.getViewTreeObserver()
                         .removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);


                Picasso.with(this.context)
                       .load(message_pic_url)
                       .placeholder(R.drawable.profile_wall_picture)
                       .resize(0, holder.message_picture.getHeight())
                       .into(holder.message_picture);
            }
        });
```

Comment: with this solution I receive the `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: At least one dimension has to be positive number.` error on rotation, this is in the fragment, any ideas as to why this may happen?

Comment: I have added check for the dimensions `> 0` and if so then `removeOnGlobalLayoutListener` and `Picasso` is called and seems to be running fine.

Comment: Hum, If i add this check, i have not this problem anymore but image is not resize ...

Comment: @Lukasz'Severiaan'Grela I had the same problem. To fix this example to match the original question you have to turn the arguments around: `.resize(holder.message_picture.getWidth(), 0)`

Comment: You gave me the idea. Thanks.

To those want to have full width image with variable height, use:

```Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
            Point size = new Point();
            display.getSize(size);
            int width = size.x;```

```.resize(width, 0)```

Comment: Why don't you just use `holder.message_picture.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    creator.resize(holder.message_picture.getWidth(), 0).into(holder.message_picture);
                }
            });` ?

Comment: I used this method, when you take the app to background and come back, `onGlobalLayout()` is not called and image won't show up.

Comment: This has problems in a ViewHolder. Seems like onGlobalLayout is not called if the item containing it is not currently in the RecyclerView.

Comment: What attributes need to be set (or not set) on the ImageView in the xml for this to work?

Comment: @JanK you can set whatever you like for the size, no attributes are really needed.  Typically I suppose you'd want either `layout_width="match_parent"` or `layout_height="match_parent"`, and for that you need the latter example.

Answer (score 91):

I came across the same issue and it took me a while to track down a solution but I finally came across something that works for me.

Firstly I changed the Picasso call to

```
Picasso.with(this.context).load(message_pic_url)
.placeholder(R.drawable.profile_wall_picture)
.into(holder.message_picture);
```

Removing the `fit` and the `centerInside`. Next you need to add the following lines to the ImageView in your XML

```
android:scaleType="fitStart"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

Hopefully it will work for you as well.

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't work for me. I can't see the pictures, getting logcat warning about the size of Bitmap (the classic message: 2048x2048 is the max size).

Comment: Sorry to hear that. That would be the drawback of this method. It is not getting Picasso to resize the image at all, just load it at it's full size. Could cause memory issues.

Comment: Thank you very much. It works like a charm, quick and easy ;)

Comment: @drspaceboo what is your `layout_width` and `layout_height` on the ImageView? I'm trying with `match_parent` and `wrap_content` respectively but it doesn't work :(

Comment: @VickyChijwani from memory I think I had `0dp` and  `match_parent` with a weight of `1` but not 100% sure and I don't think we have this in our application any more.

Comment: Thank you. The ImageView's XML saved me.

Comment: Thank you!
centerInside + adjustViewBounds
solved my question!

Comment: Works for me. Thanks!

Comment: IMO you don't need the scaletype int the xml since you are going to use adjust view bounds anyway

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you. This should be the accepted answer. :)

Answer (score 12):

May **[Accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22009875/1318946)** Answer is Useful to all but If you are binding Multiple `ViewHolder` for Multiple `Views` then you can reduce your code by Creating Class for **Transformation** and passing **ImageView** from `ViewHolder`.

```
/**
 * Created by Pratik Butani
 */
public class ImageTransformation {

    public static Transformation getTransformation(final ImageView imageView) {
        return new Transformation() {

            @Override
            public Bitmap transform(Bitmap source) {
                int targetWidth = imageView.getWidth();

                double aspectRatio = (double) source.getHeight() / (double) source.getWidth();
                int targetHeight = (int) (targetWidth * aspectRatio);
                Bitmap result = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(source, targetWidth, targetHeight, false);
                if (result != source) {
                    // Same bitmap is returned if sizes are the same
                    source.recycle();
                }
                return result;
            }

            @Override
            public String key() {
                return "transformation" + " desiredWidth";
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Calling from `ViewHolder`:

```
Picasso.with(context).load(baseUrlForImage)
                     .transform(ImageTransformation.getTransformation(holder.ImageView1))
                     .error(R.drawable.ic_place_holder_circle)
                     .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_place_holder_circle)
                     .into(holder.mMainPhotoImageView1);
```

Hope it will Help you.

Comment: Thanks, great solution for ImageView, one question: Can we do this for VideoView size same as ImageView passed in parameter ?

Comment: @Pratik i have recyclerview and when scroll fast, i got exception:Transformation transformation desiredWidth crashed with exception. Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: width and height must be > 0

Comment: While scrolling, sometimes `imageView.getWidth()` returns 0 and it causes an error `width and height must be > 0`. Any ideas how to fix this error?

Comment: In that case, may be your image url is null so check it first if null or not.

Answer (score 5):

```
    Picasso.with(this).load(url).resize(1800, 1800).centerInside().into(secondImageView)

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/SecondImage"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:visibility="gone"/>
```

This will help you with variable height of images for all devices

Answer (score 2):

```
imageView.post(new Runnable() {
      @Override public void run() {
        Picasso.with(context)
            .resize(0, imageView.getHeight())
            .onlyScaleDown()
            .into(imageView, new ImageCallback(callback, null));
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I've wrote simple helper that take care about adding layout complete listener and call into(imageView) when layout process complete.

```
public class PicassoDelegate {

private RequestCreator mRequestCreator;

public PicassoDelegate(ImageView target, RequestCreator requestCreator) {
    if (target.getWidth() > 0 && target.getHeight() > 0) {
        complete(target, requestCreator);
    } else {
        mRequestCreator = requestCreator;
        target.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new View.OnLayoutChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right, int bottom, int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom) {
                v.removeOnLayoutChangeListener(this);
                complete((ImageView) v, mRequestCreator);
            }
        });

    }

}

private void complete(ImageView target, RequestCreator requestCreator) {
    if (target.getWidth() > 0 && target.getHeight() > 0) {
        requestCreator.resize(target.getWidth(), target.getHeight());
    }

    requestCreator.into(target);
}
```

}

So you can easily use it like this for example in fragment's onViewCreated()

```
new PicassoDelegate(customerPhoto, Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(user.getPhotoUrl()).centerCrop());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class CropSquareTransformation implements Transformation {

  private int mWidth;
  private int mHeight;

  @Override public Bitmap transform(Bitmap source) {
    int size = Math.min(source.getWidth(), source.getHeight());

    mWidth = (source.getWidth() - size) / 2;
    mHeight = (source.getHeight() - size) / 2;

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(source, mWidth, mHeight, size, size);
    if (bitmap != source) {
      source.recycle();
    }

    return bitmap;
  }

  @Override public String key() {
    return "CropSquareTransformation(width=" + mWidth + ", height=" + mHeight + ")";
  }
```

More transformations: https://github.com/wasabeef/picasso-transformations

Comment: What should be the `layout_width` and `layout_height` of the `ImageView` in this case?

Answer (score 1):

extend ImageView then override onMeasure method like the following.

```
@Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec){
        Drawable d = getDrawable();

        if(d!=null && fittingType == FittingTypeEnum.FIT_TO_WIDTH){
            int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
            int height = (int) Math.ceil((float) width * (float) d.getIntrinsicHeight() / (float) d.getIntrinsicWidth());
            setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
        }else{
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually i was getting in while loading image in CustomImageView which had zoomable functionality

Error was

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Transformation transformation desiredWidth crashed with exception.
```

I solved it by editing code given from accepted answer i got the max width of my display as if my imageview width was already match_parent.

if (!imgUrl.equals("")) {

```
        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        ((Activity) context).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
        int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
        int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;

        Picasso.with(context).load(imgUrl)
                .transform(getTransformation(width, imageView))
                .into(imageView, new Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {
                        if (progressBar != null) {
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError() {
                        if (progressBar != null) {
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

    public static Transformation getTransformation(final int width, final ImageView imageView) {
        return new Transformation() {
            @Override
            public Bitmap transform(Bitmap source) {
                int targetWidth = width;
                double aspectRatio = (double) source.getHeight() / (double) source.getWidth();
                int targetHeight = (int) (targetWidth * aspectRatio);
                Bitmap result = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(source, targetWidth, targetHeight, false);
                if (result != source) {
                    // Same bitmap is returned if sizes are the same
                    source.recycle();
                }
                return result;
            }

            @Override
            public String key() {
                return "transformation" + " desiredWidth";
            }
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Picasso.get()
.load(message_pic_url)
.fit()
.centerCrop()
.placeholder(R.drawable.profile_wall_picture)
.into(holder.message_picture);
```

Try this code, Worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        imageView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                loadImageIfReady();
            }
        });

    }

    private void loadImageIfReady() {
        if (imageView.getMeasuredWidth() <= 0 || mPayload == null)
            this.finish();    // if not ready GTFO

        Picasso.with(this)
                    .load(mPayload)
                    .resize(imageView.getMeasuredWidth(), imageView.getMeasuredWidth())
                    .centerInside()
                    .into(imageView);


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the value fitXY will work for you, here is an example that worked for me :

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView_answer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/answer_image" />
```