# How can I set the density of images loaded with Picasso?

Tags: android, bitmap, picasso, pixel-density

The images I load with Picasso seem to use a density value of [DENSITY_NONE](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#DENSITY_NONE). What do I have to change to make Picasso call [.setDensity(160)](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#setDensity(int)) on the loaded images before they are displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basing myself on [another Picasso solution to resize images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21889735/resize-image-to-full-width-and-variable-height-with-picasso) I implemented a custom transformation object which sets the density of images to a constant of my own:

```
Transformation changeDensity = new Transformation()
{
    @Override public Bitmap transform(Bitmap source)
    {
        source.setDensity(160);
        return source;
    }

    @Override public String key()
    {
        return "density";
    }
};

// …later…

Picasso
    .with(context)
    .load(imageUri)
    .transform(changeDensity)
    .into(imageView);
```