# Transform Image with Picasso to match ImageView Width and maintain aspect ratio in RecyclerView

Tags: android, imageview, android-recyclerview, picasso

I have a RecyclerView with CardViews inside a staggered grid layout. Each CardView has a custom adjustable height ImageView inside. I am using Picasso to load images into the ImageView.

I am trying to first transform the image to match the width of the ImageView and set the height so that aspect ratio is maintained. I am then trying to resize the height of ImageView to match the image.

Everything works on the first load but when I scroll down my custom transformation isn't able to get the width of the ImageView it just returns 0 and this causes the app to crash.

I tried with a getViewTreeObserver like suggested in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21889735/resize-image-to-full-width-and-variable-height-with-picasso) but then only the first four pictures load, the next few images are blank, and then the first four images repeat themselves in the wrong CardViews.

Here is the code I have that loads properly but crashes on scroll:

**Recycler Adapter**

```
public class PlacesRecyclerAdapter extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<PlacesRecyclerAdapter.PlacesView> {

    ...

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final PlacesView placesView, final int i) {

        Target target = new Target() {
            @Override
            public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
                float ratio = (float) bitmap.getHeight() / (float) bitmap.getWidth();

                placesView.placeImage.setAspectRatio(ratio);
                placesView.placeImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }

            @Override
            public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {

            }
        };
        placesView.placeImage.setTag(target);

        // Setup details variables
        final Business place = mPlaces.get(i);
        String photo = place.getImage_url();

        // Load Image with Picasso
        Picasso.with(mContext)
                .load(photo)
                .transform(new FitToViewTransformation(placesView.placeImage))
                .into(target);
    }

    ...
}
```

**Custom Transformation**

```
public class FitToViewTransformation implements Transformation {
    private DynamicHeightImageView mView;

    public FitToViewTransformation(DynamicHeightImageView view) {
        mView = view;
    }

    @Override
    public Bitmap transform(Bitmap source) {
        int targetWidth = mView.getWidth(); // This returns the width on the first page load but on scrolling returns 0
        Log.v("FitToView:", "Target width: " + targetWidth);

        double aspectRatio = (double) source.getHeight() / (double) source.getWidth();
        int targetHeight = (int) (targetWidth * aspectRatio);


        Bitmap result = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(source, targetWidth, targetHeight, false);
        if (result != source) {
            // Same bitmap is returned if sizes are the same
            source.recycle();
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public String key() {
        return "transformation" + " desiredWidth";
    }
}
```

**Update 1 (failure)**

I went ahead and tried the OnGlobalLayoutListener again and I still get just the first four images then four blank images, then the first four showing again. This is how I implemented it in my onBindViewHolder:

```
placesView.placeImage.getViewTreeObserver()
        .addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        placesView.placeImage.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
        Picasso.with(mContext)
                .load(photo)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.cast_album_art_placeholder)
                .error(R.drawable.item_icon_parking)
                .transform(new FitToViewTransformation(placesView.placeImage))
                .into(target);
    }
});
```

**Update 2 (success... I guess)**

So I have found a fix, although I'm not so sure it is the right thing to do. It does work though and the app doesn't have any unwanted behavior. All I did was add an empty while loop to the beginning of my transform method like this:

```
@Override
public Bitmap transform(Bitmap source) {
    double aspectRatio = (double) source.getHeight() / (double) source.getWidth();

    while(mView.getWidth() == 0) {

    }

    int targetWidth = mView.getWidth();
    Log.v("FitToView:", "Target width: " + targetWidth);

    int targetHeight = (int) (targetWidth * aspectRatio);


    Bitmap result = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(source, targetWidth, targetHeight, false);
    if (result != source) {
        // Same bitmap is returned if sizes are the same
        source.recycle();
    }

    return result;
}
```