# Android Picasso load image to Bitmap variable cropping it to square

Tags: android, picasso, android-bitmap, bitmapfactory

I need to load some images from URI to Bitmap variables and perform some operation with them togheter. I need the bitmaps to be squared images with fixes size, scaled down and cropped. By now I use this code:

```
return Picasso.with(c).load(imageUri).resize(size, size).get();
```

but, obviously, the image will be resized without keep its aspect ratio.

I want to resize the image with these requirements:

- the smaller dimension (width or height) should be equals to `size`
- the greater dimension should be cropped to `size`, keep image centered

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21889735/resize-image-to-full-width-and-variable-height-with-picasso

Answer (score 2):

The key is using centerInside after resize. See [link](https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/226)

```
Picasso.with(c).load(imageUri).resize(size, size).centerInside().get()
```

Answer (score 0):

set your imageview height and width fix inside xml and then set image to imageview like

```
 Picasso.with(YourActivityName.this)
                        .load(imageUri)
                        .into(imageview_id);
```