# My layout is crashed after Picasso loads images

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, picasso

I'm trying to build a customized image layout which looks as following, where 4 `A`'s indicate the one `ImageView`.

```
AABC
AADE
```

When I tried to draw the layout with default `src` attributes, or when I put `placeholder` options on Picasso, the layout is rendered without a problem. However, while Picasso gradually lazy-loads each image, the layout is crashed like this. (The space below `A` is a blank space.)

```
ABC
 DE
```

How can I maintain my original layout with Picasso's lazy loading? [`CustomSquareImageView`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23907471/4286919) is a custom class which extends `ImageView` to draw a squared ImageView.

#### PartOfLayout.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/set_profile_profile_photos_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:baselineAligned="false">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <CustomSquareImageView
            android:id="@+id/set_profile_profile_photos_first"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/profile" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <CustomSquareImageView
                android:id="@+id/set_profile_profile_photos_second"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/profile" />

            <CustomSquareImageView
                android:id="@+id/set_profile_profile_photos_third"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/profile" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <CustomSquareImageView
                android:id="@+id/set_profile_profile_photos_fourth"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/profile" />

            <CustomSquareImageView
                android:id="@+id/set_profile_profile_photos_fifth"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/profile" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

#### PartOfFragment.java

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    try {
        JSONArray profilePhotos = new JSONArray(mProfile.getProfileImages());
        if (!profilePhotos.get(0).toString().isEmpty()) {
            Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(profilePhotos.get(0).toString()).
                    placeholder(R.drawable.profile).into(mProfilePhotoFirst);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

### UPDATED

The answer by the author [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20823249/resize-image-to-full-width-and-fixed-height-with-picasso?rq=1) using `.fit().centerCrop()` with `placeholder` effectively solve the problem "in the end", but in the process where Picasso is loading images, the layout is temporarily crashed because each image is in different sizes. (After it loads all the image successfully, the layout looks good.)

How can I load images without crashing the layout in the middle? I want the loaded images not to disturb the layout but be inserted directly to the layout with `centerCrop` state.

Comment: try using resize() and fix the size of image...

Comment: @NAVdroid That'd the job but I solved(actually fixed my mistake) the problem differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I used `LinearLayout`s as a image frame, all I had to do was to set `layout_width` of `LinearLayout`s to `match_parent`, not `wrap_content` or `0dp` as Android Studio suggested.

My new XML looks like this.

#### NewPartOfLayout.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/set_profile_profile_photos_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:baselineAligned="false">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <CustomSquareImageView
            android:id="@+id/set_profile_profile_photos_first"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/profile" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <CustomSquareImageView
                android:id="@+id/set_profile_profile_photos_second"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/profile" />

            <CustomSquareImageView
                android:id="@+id/set_profile_profile_photos_third"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/profile" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <CustomSquareImageView
                android:id="@+id/set_profile_profile_photos_fourth"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/profile" />

            <CustomSquareImageView
                android:id="@+id/set_profile_profile_photos_fifth"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/profile" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```