# Picasso crop to a view

Tags: android, picasso

How would I use picasso to crop an image to an ImageView?

Default seems to scale it down so the whole thing shows fit seems to stretch it.
Centercrop by itself breaks.
fit centercrop seems to be the same as just fit

Comment: Use `.fit().centerCrop()` [Answer, which help me a lot](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20824141/5439793)

Answer (score 13):

Try using `centerCrop()`

```
Picasso.with(mContext)
.load(url)
.centerCrop()
.resize(yourImageView.getMeasuredWidth(),yourImageView.getMeasuredHeight())
.error(R.drawable.error)
.placeholder(R.drawable.blank_img)
.into(yourImageView);
```

You have to add `addOnPreDrawListener` listener otherwise you will get 0 for width and height when the imageview is not drawn. Go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4680660/1503155) for details on how to use `addOnPreDrawListener`.

Comment: centercrop by itself gives an error   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Center crop requires calling resize with positive width and height. What is the error of Picasso mean?

Comment: @FrickenHamster you are right. You need to add resize. Check my edit.

Comment: This solution seems to just set the crop based on whatever values I have in resize. I would like it to crop based on the size of the imageview, which is located in a cardview

Answer (score 8):

`CenterCrop()` is a cropping technique that scales the image so that it fills the requested bounds of the `ImageView` and then crops the extra. The `ImageView` will be filled completely, but the entire image might not be displayed.

```
Picasso  
.with(context)
.load(UsageExampleListViewAdapter.eatFoodyImages[0])
.resize(600, 200) // resizes the image to these dimensions (in pixel)
.centerCrop() 
.into(imageViewResizeCenterCrop);
```

`CenterInside()` is a cropping technique that scales the image so that both dimensions are equal to or less than the requested bounds of the `ImageView`. The image will be displayed completely, but might not fill the entire `ImageView`.

```
Picasso  
.with(context)
.load(UsageExampleListViewAdapter.eatFoodyImages[0])
.resize(600, 200)
.centerInside() 
.into(imageViewResizeCenterInside);
```

The discussed options should cover your needs for functionality regarding image resizing and scaling. There is one last helper functionality of Picasso, which can be very useful: `fit()`.

```
Picasso  
.with(context)
.load(UsageExampleListViewAdapter.eatFoodyImages[0])
.fit()
// call .centerInside() or .centerCrop() to avoid a stretched image
.into(imageViewFit);
```

Answer (score 3):

You must call resize before calling centerCrop or centerInside() methods otherwise Picasso complains about target width/height being 0.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
ImageView imageView;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
}

@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    if (hasFocus) {
        Picasso.with(this)
                .load("http://i.imgur.com/removed.png")
                .resize(imageView.getMeasuredWidth(), imageView.getMeasuredHeight())
                .centerCrop() // or centerInside()
                .into(imageView);
    }
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
}
}
```

And here's the imageView defined within layout:

```
 <ImageView
    android:layout_width="160dp"
    android:layout_height="160dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    />
```

Comment: I actually have the imageview inside a recyclerview,
so getmeasuredwidth and height end up being 0 at onBindViewHolder.
How would I get the size then?
thanks

Comment: @Fricken Hamster, maybe too late, but you can use Picasso's `.fit()`. It waits until `getMeasure` and than do the rest.