# Crop image as square with picasso

Tags: android, image, picasso, android-image

How can I crop image to square using picasso library on Android?

I need following:
[image: cat one]

and I also need [image: cat two]

Comment: This question has been answered here, maybe it can help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30134438/picasso-crop-to-a-view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following project provides a lot of different transformations for Picasso

https://github.com/wasabeef/picasso-transformations

The one you are interested is named `CropSquareTransformation` and you can apply it by using the following code

```
Picasso.with(mContext)
       .load(R.drawable.demo)
       .transform(transformation)
       .transform(new CropSquareTransformation())
       .into(holder.image);
```

You could add the dependency or copy and paste the classes you need.

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

Using a custom imageview:

```
public class SquareImageView extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView {
    public SquareImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public SquareImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public SquareImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredWidth(), getMeasuredWidth()); //Snap to width
    }
}
```

In your xml:

```
 <com.my.package.SquareImageView
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```