# Showing Can't load the image

Tags: android, image, cropper

I'm trying to download an image from internet and pass it to the device's default cropper but it's showing can't load image.

My code is:

```
Intent cropApps = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
cropApps.setType("image/*");
List<ResolveInfo> list = this.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(cropApps, 0);
int size = list.size();
if (size == 0)
{
    Toast.makeText(this, "Can not find image crop app", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
else
{
    Uri picUri = Uri.parse("https://www.irononsticker.com/images/Doraemom43.jpg");
    ResolveInfo res = list.get(0);
    Intent cropIntent = new Intent();
    cropIntent.setClassName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name);
    cropIntent.setDataAndType(picUri, "image/*");
    cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 800);
    cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 800);
    cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
    cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
    cropIntent.putExtra("scale", true);
    cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
    startActivity(cropIntent);
```

Comment: [Android does not have a `CROP` `Intent`](http://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html). There are many [image cropping libraries for Android](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/45). Please use one.

Comment: I agree, I use picasso for this things and works like a charm.

Comment: Sir can you please share your code with me @jeprubio

Comment: It's easy to find, have a look at the answer in here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43281758/crop-image-as-square-with-picasso

Answer (score -1):

what you need to do is go to the file, click properties, and copy the location.
example:  (r'C:\Users\Owner\Downloads\game\yourimagename.png')
you notice that after you paste the loctation, put a '\' and click on the file you want.

hope this helps

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! I'm sure you wanted to help but I believe this isn't really what the author had in mind. If you take a closer look then it seems that the image should be downloaded from a specific URI and not loaded from a system file. Please, consider updating your answer to make it more helpful. If you don't know the answer to the question then please consider removing it. Cheers!