# Crop white spaces from images

Tags: android, image-processing, picasso, android-image, android-bitmap

I have a service that download images and uses picasso to show it in a CardView.

```
Picasso.with(context).load(beer.getLabelLarge()).fit().centerCrop().into(imgBeerLabel);
```

But these images comes involved with an undesirable white space:

[image]

[image]

I want to trim these images and show only the label, without the white border, and resizing it to ImageView dimensions.

-- EDIT

The white part has variable size.

The problem is the same as reported in this question:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12175991/crop-image-white-space-automatically-using-jquery
```

But there it was solved with a lot of code, which I would like to avoid at this time.

One possible solution that would help me would be to focus on a specific square within the image and zoom in on that part, making it fill the entire screen, regardless of the size of the white part.

The result expected is:

[image]

Is there a way to do this using Picasso and Transformations?

Comment: do you know the label width and height. You can use transformations to crop to required size

Comment: Maybe you can try something like the answer on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12175991/crop-image-white-space-automatically-using-jquery

Comment: @Raghunandan no. it is variable.

Comment: @AnthonyJones The problem is the same, but I thought there might be a less programmatic solution.

Comment: May this will be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43281758/crop-image-as-square-with-picasso

Answer (score 2):

I end up creating a new Transform implementation based on code found in [this library](https://github.com/wasabeef/picasso-transformations).

It looks for the first different pixel in both sides, in the vertical and horizontal, and crops the bitmap from there. It's not perfect, but it suits my needs.

```
public class CropMiddleFirstPixelTransformation implements Transformation {
    private int mWidth;
    private int mHeight;


    @Override
    public Bitmap transform(Bitmap source) {
        int width = source.getWidth();
        int height = source.getHeight();

        int[] horizontalMiddleArray = new int[width];
        source.getPixels(horizontalMiddleArray, 0, width, 0, height / 2, width, 1);

        int[] verticalMiddleArray = new int[height];
        source.getPixels(verticalMiddleArray, 0, 1, width / 2, 0, 1, height);

        int left = getFirstNonWhitePosition(horizontalMiddleArray);
        int right = getLastNonWhitePosition(horizontalMiddleArray);

        int top = getFirstNonWhitePosition(verticalMiddleArray);
        int bottom = getLastNonWhitePosition(verticalMiddleArray);

        mWidth = right - left;
        mHeight = bottom - top;


        if (!isNegative(left, right, top, bottom)) {
            return source;
        }

        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(source, left, top, mWidth , mHeight);
        source.recycle();
        return bitmap;

    }

    private boolean isNegative(int... values) {
        for (int i : values) {
            if (i < 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;

    }

    private int getFirstNonWhitePosition(int[] horizontalMiddleArray) {
        int left = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < horizontalMiddleArray.length; i++) {
            if (i == 0) {
                left = horizontalMiddleArray[i];
            }
            if (left != horizontalMiddleArray[i]) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    private int getLastNonWhitePosition(int[] horizontalMiddleArray) {
        int right = 0;
        int length = horizontalMiddleArray.length;
        for (int i = length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
            if (i == length - 1) {
                right = horizontalMiddleArray[i];
            }
            if (right != horizontalMiddleArray[i]) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }


    @Override
    public String key() {
        return "CropMiddleFirstPixelTransformation(width=" + mWidth + ", height=" + mHeight + ")";
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like your isNegative method returns true if all of the values are positive. Is this intended? I believe that this may also crop images unexpectedly if there is a legitimate white pixel on the outside of the image such as in the orange and white Kronos logo.

Answer (score 1):

Use concept of Vector Image or Nine Patch image.Url is given below

For Vector Image :- https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio.html

For ninePatch image https://developer.android.com/studio/write/draw9patch.html

Comment: I don't understand how this might be used in a dynamic way.  can you provide more information?