# How to make move and scale activity

Tags: android, imageview, gallery

I want the user to upload his profile picture but I want to force him to crop it before .

How can I do that ?

[image: like this]

I try to do it from scratch but it will take a lot of time i guess , Is there any library can do the job for me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few way to do, First and suggested way use **library** or handle it with android intent

> com.android.camera.action.CROP

at your own

I'v use this library for a while and it's great

https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) library. It is very easy to use.

For example:

```
 Picasso.with(mContext)
  .load(url)
  .centerCrop()
  .resize(yourImageView.getMeasuredWidth(),yourImageView.getMeasuredHeight())
  .error(R.drawable.error)
  .placeholder(R.drawable.blank_img)
  .into(yourImageView);
```

Comment: Is this feature available by glide ?
and where I need to put this code ? any more details ?

Comment: See this how to crop a picture with picasso. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30134438/picasso-crop-to-a-view

Comment: this will crop the image only i want the use to move and scale to choose witch part of the picture he want