# My image is not stretch according to parent size

Tags: android, android-imageview, viewflipper

I want that my image size is exactly the size of parent element

I already use this "android:adjustViewBounds="true"" but its not working. I try many times but fail

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".6">

        <ViewFlipper
            android:id="@+id/viewflipper"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:autoStart="true"
            android:flipInterval="2000" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/background" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/background" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/background" />
    </ViewFlipper>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You need to add the 'scaleType' attribute to your layout: take a look at ::https://proandroiddev.com/a-guide-for-android-imageview-scaletype-and-adjustviewbounds-64a1e4a35503

Comment: I will recommend using Picasso lib, fast and easy!
Ref:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30134438/picasso-crop-to-a-view][1]

Comment: thank you for new knownlege

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try combine your ImageView with scaleType and adjustViewBounds like this:

```
         <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />
```

You can use fitXY | centerCrop | fitCenter and others

See more options for scaleType here:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType