# how to send from onactivityresult uri path to another activity and change it to image

Tags: android

In the below code I am getting an image from sd card , and sending the image through an intent, 
however I want to change the code to send the path of the image , and not the image itself

```
  @Override
       protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

           super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {

                //file name
                filePath = data.getData();
                try {
                //  Bundle extras2 = data.getExtras();
                    bitmap  = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);
                    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();               
                   byte imageInByte[] = stream.toByteArray();                    
                  Intent i = new Intent(this, AddImage.class);
                  i.putExtra("image", imageInByte);
                  startActivity(i);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();     }   }   }    




and here I am receiving the image



     byte[] byteArray = getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("image");
       //      encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64);
            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
          ImageView imageview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            imageview.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

Also I tried  this but it didn't work:

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

           super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {

                filePath = data.getData();

                  Intent i = new Intent(this, AddImage.class);
                  i.putExtra("imagepath", filePath);
                  startActivity(i);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();     }   }}
```

but how to receive the uri path

`geturi().getintent()` ?
and then get the image

edit--

I got error `nullpointerexception uri string` here

```
    img.setImageURI(Uri.parse(imagePath ));
```

this is the code

```
  String imagePath = getIntent().getStringExtra("imagePath");
            ImageView img=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            img.setImageURI(Uri.parse(imagePath ));

            Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)img.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
            Bitmap out = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 500, 500, false); 
            // bitmap is the image 
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
           out.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 60, stream); 
           out.recycle();

/*       byte[] byteArray = getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("image");

           //      encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64);
//              bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);*/
           //   ImageView imageview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
                img.setImageBitmap(out);
```

i am sending intent like this

filePath = data.getData();
  Intent i = new Intent(this,
                        AddImage.class);
  i.putExtra("imagepath", filePath);
 startActivity(i);

Comment: better send the path in string or save in sharedprefernces

Comment: @quicklearner so you are saying to get the path from onactivityresult , save it in a sharedpreference then take it to another activity ?

Comment: save it in first activity then get it in the next activity

Comment: String uri = getIntent().getStringExtra("imagePath");

Comment: @quicklearner and arun , can you show me a simple example ?

Comment: use should send imagePath not the image so it would be better, just send the imagepath from one activity to another

Comment: @quicklearner yes thats what I am asking

Answer (score 2):

AddImage Activity

```
   onCreate(...)
   {
        ....
        String imagePath = getIntent().getStringExtra("imagePath");
        ImageView img=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        img.setImageURI(Uri.parse(imagePath ));

        Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)img.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
        Bitmap out = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 500, 500, false); 
        // bitmap is the image 
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        out.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 60, stream);
        img.setImageBitmap(out); 
        bitmap.recycle();
        ....
   }
```

Comment: but I need to compress the image , how to add those ?
                    Bitmap out = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 500, 500, false); // bitmap is the image 
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    out.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 60, stream);
                    out.recycle();

Comment: after getting the image I want to decrease the size

Comment: I got error while applying your code , check my edit , can you identify the problem ?

Comment: remove the out.recycle()

Comment: but recylce is important if I want to load another image 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3823799/android-bitmap-recycle-how-does-it-work

Comment: you need to recycle bitmap.recycle(). Because out is currently used.

Comment: still same error at same line ..  what is the problem can you help ? @arun