# image is not covering full width of the background of app

Tags: android, picasso

I am using an image of size 1080*1920 in my app using picasso library but my image is not covering entire view horizontally. Here is the code for picasso

```
private void initBackgroundImage() {
    ImageView background = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_background);
    Picasso.with(this).load(R.drawable.background).resize(70,120).centerCrop().into(background);
}
```

I have tried different width and height in resize method but not able to cover all the view.

Comment: have you set scale type in imageview?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resize image to full width and fixed height with Picasso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20823249/resize-image-to-full-width-and-fixed-height-with-picasso)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to specify the `ScaleType` of your `Imageview`

Try using `fit()`:

```
Picasso.with(this).load(R.drawable.background)
        .fit().resize(70,120).centerCrop().into(background);
```

or `.centerCrop()`

```
 Picasso.with(this).load(R.drawable.background)
        .centerCrop().resize(70,120).centerCrop().into(background);
```

Comment: Sorry about revision #2, I was editing and didn't see your edit before I pushed the edit

Answer (score 0):

```
Try using     Picasso.with(this).load(R.drawable.background).resize(70,120).fit().into(background);
or
Picasso.with(this).load(R.drawable.background).resize(70,120).into(background);

Don't use centerCrop() property if you are trying to show full image without cropping. Try using different image styles like centerInside() or fit()

Hope it may works!
```

Comment: when I used resize(70,120).fit().into(background): there is an error, app crashes, error stated by android monitor that fit() can not be used with resize(). I am using picasso library 2.5.2

Comment: refer this link https://futurestud.io/tutorials/picasso-image-resizing-scaling-and-fit